# Rich Snippets: Should the data be reflected on page?

Tags: seo, schema, google-rich-snippets

I have some schema data for product reviews, but none of it actually prints to the page, it's only there in the background for Google.

Is this a bad idea? Do Google look for it on page as well? I can't find the answer anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Schema markup in your webpage content to make the relevant sections such as dates and reviews of the products visible to the searcher in the form of rich snippets. It is definitely not a bad idea to include structured data in the HTML of your webpage because Google shows additional data like the review, recipes, and events in the meta description of the link of the webpage. This will also help searchers to visit your webpage for product review due to the additional data provided as a rich snippet, and as a result, boost your SERP ranking.